# How to boot the Mele A1000 in recovery mode

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery

I installed `CWM` on my `Mele A1000` and I was able to reboot into recovery mode
using adb.

At which point I got the `CWM` menu where I was able to install files from SD, wipe cache etc...

After installing all the files (`Cyanogen`) I rebooted, now when the device starts all I see is the `Cyanogen` splash screen for a few minutes and then a message indicating:

> Encryption Unsuccessful. Encryption was interrupted and can't
>   complete. As a result the data on your tablet is no longer accessible.
>
> To resume using your tablet, you must perform a factory reset. When
>   you set up your tablet after the reset ....

This message looks like it's part of the standard Android system.

Since `CWM` is installed I should be able to access it in order to install something
else,
but I cannot figure out how to reboot in recovery/cwm mode. There is no hardware button other than the power button on the `Mele A1000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the encryption screen comes up, Android may have gotten far enough in the bootprocess for the adb server to start. If you have adb set up on the computer, check and see if the computer can recognize the phone by typing `adb devices`. If you see device with a serial number, then just simply type `adb reboot recovery`. (If you don't have adb, there are several guides that can be found via Google that explain how to get it set up.)